# Is possible have a folder with multiples repositories keeping the history?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I tried to find an answer to this question but I didn't. I found out about sub-modules and sub-tree and sub-modules seems pretty similar to what I want to achieve.

I have multiples projects with their git history but they haven't a remote repository. I want to put all of them in a folder and push it to github. However, I want to keep the git history individually of each of them and I don't want to create additional repositories.

Is possible to do it?

I was even thinking in rename the folder .git in each repository to upload and when I download the parent repository rename the .git folder to get again the history.

Answer (score 0):

Anything in that territory is certainly possible, run low-level commands that operate underneath the `HEAD` ref the ordinary-workflow convenience commands use, and keep the manifest for each in its own index by setting `GIT_INDEX_FILE` in the environment, but none of this is hard. It just seems a bit unnecessary. You can follow individual files' histories with an ordinary git log, so you'd probably do well to figure out exactly what concrete effects you're trying to achieve or avoid here. You're going to need to do that anyway to implement it.